# response to phpMyAdmin sniffing

Tags: mysql, security, phpmyadmin, apache2, sniffing

I have been developing and running a small website using apache2 for several years, and ~once per day, my error log is spammed with requests for nonexistent files related to PHPMyAdmin.  My site does not use PHP, though there is an active MySQL server (using non-conventional settings).  All requests are made over a span of 2-5 seconds.  Am I safe in assuming these are all requests sniffing for vulnerabilities, or is there any instance in which a legitimate site/company/server might need this information?  e.g. advertisers and such?  As it is, I've got a script setup to automatically ban any IP that attempts to access one of these nonexistent files.  Also, if all of these requests are people searching for vulnerabilities, is there any way to have some fun with the perpetrators?  e.g. a well-placed redirect to the NSA?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure this question is appropriate for SO.  Maybe better for http://security.stackexchange.com.  But my 2¢: I can think of no legit reason for anyone probing your site in this fashion (maybe a grad student doing research perhaps?). Most likely the computers behind this are infected and acting as zombies. It is highly unlikely that anyone will notice the redirect to the NSA (neither the NSA nor the zombie master). Out of curiosity from what countries does the traffic originate?  We see most of this from China.

Comment: Related question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13637/disadvantages-of-a-fake-phpmyadmin-honeypot-that-causes-ip-blacklisting-and-robo

Comment: @AllInOne The US and China probably represent about a third of the total, each.  Most of the rest appear to be coming in blocks (e.g. 21 in a row from the Philippines or 5 in a row from Vietnam), but there are also a number of outliers (single hits over several months from Italy, Latvia, France, Denmark, etc.).  I hadn't really checked the sources before, but yeah that makes sense if they're zombies.  Thanks for pointing me to security.stackexchange.com; should I delete this topic?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry about. Most likely those will be automated bots that search for publicly released vulnerabilities (or their identifiers, such as a specific url), default box set ups, default username/password combinations etc. Those bots are looking for quick and easy exploitation, so normally they will only search for a  couple of urls and then move on, thus there is nothing to worry about. You will have to get to used to this though, because as the site will grow, those may occur more commonly (then you might want to start thinking about restricting access by IP range etc)

Answer (score 1):

To improve security against brute-force login attempts, version 4.1.0-rc1 has an optional reCAPTCHA module.